# how to set permissions on a folder that is in SVN via Mac Terminal

Tags: svn

I have a folder in SVN that i am connecting to via Mac's Terminal. What is the commands to set a folder's perms to 777?

Answer (score 1):

MacOSX has [a fully certified POSIX compliant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X#Software) OS. This also means that the standard Unix command line tools are available, so to change the permissions on a file or folder you can use:

```
chmod 777 folder
```

Looking at your comment on another answer, it seems that you want the default checkout permissions to be `777`. [This is not possible with pure svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56149/storing-file-permissions-in-subversion-repository). One possible workaround might be to do:

```
umask 0
svn co folder
```

Another possibility for you is to use [asvn](http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/contrib/client-side/asvn), as this is a wrapper around svn that does store permissions for you.

Answer (score 0):

easy:

```
chmod 777 folder
```

However, since subversion only cares about the contents of the files, you can't change those permissions in the repository. If you really need to maintain those permissions, you might want to try and make a simple checkout script that will `chmod 777` them after you do a checkout.

Another option would be to `svn co` the folder copy it somewhere else, `svn rm` the original, move the copy back to the original directory, perform the `chmod 777` and `svn ci` the folder. Although that might be more trouble than it's worth.

On another note, if you are just trying to get executable privileges on a file, you can use

```
svn propset svn:executable '' [filename]
```

but that doesn't seem to be what you are wanting.

Comment: dont i do 'svn chmod 777 folder'?

Comment: subversion does not store the permissions in the repository, you can only set permissions on local files.

Comment: you cant, svn command doesnt have a chmod sub command

Comment: really? so would i have to set the chmod on FTP or something that svn is connected to?

Comment: That may work, but then you run the risk of corrupting the whole repository.

Comment: so what would u suggest if i need to chmod a dir that is in svn? what would zipcodeman do?

Comment: If you look at my answer, I have updated it with a few possible scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

The MacOS X Terminal == unix commandline, so all online documentation you see relating to the unix or linux command-line and the subversion command-line client will work just fine.